# Filtering ISO date by hour

Tags: python, django

I was trying to get the number of insurance claims by Day and what time it occurred. For Example, it is March 22 today and there were claims on 8 am another in 12noon. I was trying to get all the claim count this day and what hour did the claims occured.

I did try using modified_at__hour but it doesn't show what I needed.
**Sample code for claims per week and show what day it was claimed**

```
class GetClaimsCompare_week(APIView):
def get_claim_count(self, claims_data, claim_type):
    claims_count = claims_data.filter(claim_type = claim_type).count()
    return claims_count

def get_claims_type(self, claims_per_day):
    return claims_per_day.claim_type
    #return claims_data.claim_type

def get(self, request):
    today = datetime.now()
    claims_data = Claims.objects.filter(modified_at__day = today.day)

    claims_per_day = claims_data.annotate(day = TruncDay('modified_at')).values('day').annotate(claim_type=Count('id'))

    labels = []

    claims_type = list(set(map(self.get_claims_type, claims_data)))

    final = {}

    for claims in claims_per_day:
        labels.append(claims['day'])
        #data.append(claims['claims'])
        for claim_type in claims_type:
            final[claim_type] = self.get_claim_count(claims_data, claim_type)

    context = {
        'Date(s)': labels,
        'Claims on this date': final
    }

    return Response(context)
```